# About sum of random variables with specific PDF

Tags: probability-theory, random-functions

Given two independent random variables X and Y, where CDF and PDF for X are:
\begin{equation}
F_X(x) = \Biggl\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                 0 & \mbox{if $x \le 0$}\\
                 1-(x-a)^2/a^2 & \mbox{if $0\le x \le a$}\\
                 1 & \mbox{if $x\geq a$}
                 \end{array}
         \
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = \Biggl\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                 \frac{2}{a}\Big(1-\frac{x}{a}\Big) & \mbox{if $0\le x \le a$}\\
                 0 & \mbox{otherwise}
                 \end{array}
         \
\end{equation}

$Y$ has the very same distributions.

Consider now a new random variable $D$ given by $D = X+Y$.

Obtain the CDF of $D$ ( $F_D(d)$ ).

What I've done so far is to use the convolution formula over two intervals: when $d \le a$ and $a\le d$.

When $d \le a$:
\begin{equation}
F_D(d)=\int^d_0 f_X(x) F_Y(d-x)dx\\
F_D(d)=\int^d_0 \frac{2}{a}\Big(1-\frac{x}{a}\Big)(1-(d-x-a)^2/a^2)dx\\
F_D(d)=\frac{d^2(d-6a)(d-2a)}{6a^4}
\end{equation}

For $a \le d$:

\begin{equation}
F_D(d)=\int^a_{d-a} f_X(x) F_Y(d-x)dx\\
F_D(d)=\int^a_{d-a}\frac{2}{a}\Big(1-\frac{x}{a}\Big)(1-(d-x-a)^2/a^2)dx\\
F_D(d)=-\frac{(d-2a)^2(d^2-4ad-2a^2)}{6a^4}
\end{equation}

However, when I checked if the CDFs converges to 1 as $d$ increases, I obtained nonesense. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When $a\leq d$, there may be values of $X\leq d-a$ such that $X+Y\leq d$. You are missing the corresponding term in your $a\leq d$ case, i.e. the first line of that case should read $F_D(d) = \int_{d-a}^ a f_X(x) F_Y(d-x) dx + F_X(d-a)$.

Comment: many thanks alw..problem solved..cheers